# Core Data with only one Data Context. Is it right?

Tags: iphone, ios, architecture, core-data, datacontext

I'm trying to make my first application using Objective C + Core Data, but I'm not sure it's the correct way, as it feels really weird to me.

- I have only one data context, which I create at launch time, in the Application Delegate. This data context is used for all the operations (read, write). In another environment (C# and LINQ for example), I try to make these operations as unitary as possible. Here it seems I just have to create the data context once, and work with it without closing it ever (except when the application exits).
- I also have an asynchronous operation in which I update this data. Of course, it uses the same data context again. It works, but doesn't feel right.
- My Application Delegate keeps a NSArray of the objects contained in Core Data. I use this same NSArray in all my views.

I would actually naturally close the data context once I got all the objects I require, but... aren't the objects always attached to the data context? If I close or release the data context, all these objects will get releases as well, right?

As you can notice, there is something I'm missing here :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSManagedObjectContext` to which you refer is more of a "scratchpad" than a database connection. Objects are created, amended, destroyed in this working area, and only persisted ("written to the database" if you prefer) when you tell the MOC to save state. You can (and should) `init` and `release` MOCs if you are working in separate threads, but the App Delegate makes a MOC available so that all code executing on the main thread can use the same context. This is both convenient, and saves you from having to ensure that multiple MOCs are kept in sync with each other.

By keeping an `NSArray` of Core Data objects, you are in effect duplicating its functionality. Is there any reason for not working with an NSSet of Core Data objects provided by the MOC?

If you are working asynchronously, then you should not be sharing an `NSManagedObjectContext` object across threads, as they are not thread-safe. Instead, create one for each thread, but set them to use same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. This will serialise their access to the persisted data, but you'll need to use notifications to make them each aware of the others changes.

There is a good tutorial/description on how to use Core Data on multiple threads here: 
http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/

Comment: You right, I should used NSSet instead of my NSArray, that would be better, I just didn't knew about it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, that clears many things. To have one context / thread makes sense, that's now what I do, and I use the notifications (I didn't knew this feature neither). Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

1) CORE DATA AND THREADS, WITHOUT THE HEADACHE
http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/

2) Concurrency with Core Data
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

3) Multi-Context CoreData
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/